# How to add a class to record activity?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net, generics

I have a class library doing some CRUD operations for different areas of the system. One common requirement i have is to record the activity. My project is structured so i have an Interface and a class uses that interface.

```
public interface Users
{
 void AddUser(User u);
}

public interface Products
{
 void AddProducts(Product p);
}

Likewise my class code is similar to 

public class Users : DataContext, IUsers
{
 void AddUser(User u)
 {
   Context.User.InsertOnSubmit(u);
   Context.SubmitChanges();
   // AddActivity("User was added");
 }
}

public class Products : DataContext, IProducts
{
 void AddProducts(Product p)
 {
   Context.Products.InsertOnSubmit(p);
   Context.SubmitChanges();
 // AddActivity("Product was added");
 }
}
```

This works fine but i need to add all the activity that occurs i.e. when a user adds a product or user.

Considering this would be re-used across other similar classes as above, i would like to minimise repeating/copying the code. I did consider using an `abstract` class but received an object no instantiated error so not sure if my approach is wrong or missed something. I dont want to my classes to inherit a `UserActivity` Interface as that would mean i need to copy the code into that particular class for it to work. This one class would be doing the same type of tasks (just add a record).

How could i add another class to my projects which does one task of recording the activity but if i need to make a change to the Activity insertion method i can do this in one place instead of going through all the classes?

Comment: look into using AoP-> Unity.Interception.Interceptors ?

Comment: Are you referring to this https://koukia.ca/using-microsoft-unity-interceptor-for-a-cleaner-code-aop-55e283c5cba7? If so I'm using DBML files to access the data so not sure if this would help?

Comment: sure, or this https://github.com/siccolo/IoC-Using-MSUnity. In your "interceptor", you have IMethodInvocation->MethodBase, or IMethodInvocation-> Target which you could use to gather more information about which method is being intercepted.

Comment: Sorry im lost. All i would like to do is have a better, cleaner approach to add ActivityLogs across multiple classes without too much maintenance. Im not sure what the link would involve? Any examples i could follow?

Comment: i have working example at https://github.com/siccolo/IoC-Using-MSUnity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Computer, - too long for a comment, so I'll post as an "answer",

using Unity.UnityContainer, you "attach" activity logger -

```
    container.RegisterType<IProducts, Products>(
            new Interceptor<InterfaceInterceptor>()
            , new InterceptionBehavior<LoggingAspect>());, 

    ....
    public class LoggingAspect : IInterceptionBehavior, ILogger
    {
        public IMethodReturn Invoke(IMethodInvocation input, GetNextInterceptionBehaviorDelegate getNext)
        {
                //  log activity
                WriteLog($"{DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss")} --> {input.MethodBase.Name}");
                // Invoke the next behavior in the chain. 
                var result = getNext()(input, getNext);
                return result;
        }
    }
```

Comment: @Computer, - so how did you implement your activity logger?

Answer (score 1):

Create a class that inherits from DataContext. 
Replace the base class in Users and Products with the class that you've created.

```
public class User 
{

}

public class Product 
{

}

public class Actions : DataContext
{
    public void AddMessage(string Msg)
    {
        MessageAction += Msg;
    }

    public string MessageAction { get; private set; }


}

public interface IUsers 
{
    void AddUser(User u);
}

public interface IProducts 
{
    void AddProducts(Product p);
}

public class Users : Actions, IUsers
{

    public void AddUser(User u)
    {
        Context.User.InsertOnSubmit(u);
        Context.SubmitChanges();
        base.AddMessage("Add User");
    }
}

public class Products : Actions, IProducts
{

    public void AddProducts(Product p)
    {
        Context.Products.InsertOnSubmit(p);
        Context.SubmitChanges();
        base.AddMessage("Add Products");

    }
}
```